# Numbering maths in align* environment

Tags: formatting, align

I have only started using LaTeX recently so this is a beginner question.

I'm trying to code up small sections of maths relating to three different parts of a question, (i), (ii), and (iii). As these maths sections all have the same format, I'd like them to be aligned so that the equals signs sit in the same place in every line. The only way I have managed to do this is by using three separate align* environments, since using align* inside enumerate was giving me problems. This however means that the different sections aren't lined up as I would like. My current code is below:

```
(i)
\begin{align*}
8 &= -1 \cdot 2^3 \\
    & \implies v_2(8) = 3 
\end{align*}    

(ii)
\begin{align*}
126 &= 2^1 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7^1 \\
    &\implies v_2(126) = 1 \\
\end{align*}

(iii)
\begin{align*}
3 &= 2^0 \cdot 3^1  \\
    & \implies v_2(3) = 0 \\
4   & =             2^2 \\
    & \implies v_2(4) = 2 \\
    & \implies      v_2(\sfrac{3}{4}) = v_2(3) - v_2(4) = -2 
\end{align*}
```

This code gives me quite a disorganised looking output. If anybody can help me neaten this up I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that .

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,amsmath,amssymb,xfrac}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item 
$\begin{aligned}[t]
\phantom{00}8 &= -1 \cdot 2^3 \\
    & \implies v_2(8) = 3 
\end{aligned}$    

\item
$\begin{aligned}[t]
126 &= 2^1 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7^1 \\
    &\implies v_2(126) = 1 \\
\end{aligned}$

\item
$\begin{aligned}[t]
\phantom{00}3 &= 2^0 \cdot 3^1  \\
    & \implies v_2(3) = 0 \\
4   & =             2^2 \\
    & \implies v_2(4) = 2 \\
    & \implies      v_2(\sfrac{3}{4}) = v_2(3) - v_2(4) = -2 
\end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I used `\phantom` here to arrange the left hand side of each alignment has the same width.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.